# How to run a custom application through Kisok in Linux

Tags: linux

I need to know if there is any OpenSource kiosk software, which i can use to run my custom desktop based application, to run on a POS (Point of Sale).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's lots. Actually it doesn't need any custom software - it's just a specific configuration of the OS. There is a kiosk extension for Firefox. [Here's a description](http://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Linux_Kiosk) of how to set it up using a bootable CD / Ubuntu, [here's one](http://www.alandmoore.com/blog/2011/11/05/creating-a-kiosk-with-linux-and-x11-2011-edition/) using the Chrome browser, there's a [puppy image](http://puppylinux.org/wikka/Education) too - and there's lots more on Google.